# Sorting out array of parent child relations where two children share a parent from an array and display it using div

Tags: javascript, php, css, neo4j

I have the following data which gets served from a neo4j query, The data that gets sent back is in the format

```
home->parent->child1
home->parent->child2

home->parent2->child1

home->parent3->child1
home->parent3->child2
home->parent3->child3
```

I am trying to use javascript to display html which should be like this

```
<div id="parent1">
  <div id="child1"></div>
  <div id="child2"></div>
</div>
<div id="parent2">
  <div id="child1"></div>
</div>
```

i tried loopong throigh the query and trying to get the parent to be the index of an object and the child to be values under it

i would do this like this in php

```
$jsonContents = (object)("parent"=>"child","parent"=>"child"....);
$array = array();
foreach($jsonContents as $jsCo=>$jsoCont){
  $array[$jsoCont->parent][] = $jsoCont->child;
}
```

this would return the

$array as

```
home->parent1->[0]->child
             ->[1]->child
      parent2->[0]->child...
```

This would let me avoid the check for uniqueness of the home parent category as well as put them in a hierarchy so i can interpret it properly in my View part of MVC, to create my div structure.

this is the url for the example json data

http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=bdda268982eb431d361c25e9035bbc99

Answer (score 0):

No answers to this, solved it by myself.
Here

```
var data = 'data shown in link above';
var myArr = [];

$.each(data, function(index, element) {
  var parent = String(element.parent.properties.name);
  var child = String(element.child.properties.name);

  if(myArr[parent]){
    myArr[parent][(myArr[parent].length)] = child;
  } else {
    myArr[parent] = Array(child);
  }

});
```

Hope this helps people. :)